# mpi compiler or local host for secure shell client

Tags: mpi

is there any way to test MPI code online ?

also I have secure shell client program how I can run it to work in local host?

generally I need to work on MPI from my personal computer.

thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any sort of information regarding the setup you have and that is extremely valuable to guide you in the right direction. That being said, you can find multiple open-source MPI implementations (such as OpenMPI [[1](http://www.openmpi.org)]). For the particular case of OpenMPI, I can say that I have it installed in my laptop and I can run MPI applications from there. I suggest you to take a look at its building instructions [[2](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building)] as well as its running instructions [[3](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running)].

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of MPI implementations available for free to install on your computer (or cluster). If you're running a PC, you can get MS-MPI. For a Mac or Linux, he most popular general purpose implementations are MPICH and Open MPI. Both are available from their websites or in your favorite package manager.

You can use any of these to run small tests on your personal machine, even with multiple processes. Obviously, the performance won't be as great, but it's good for debugging a few ranks.